# Paho MQTT Client import?

Tags: python, paho

I don't want each time I import MQTT client object, it create a new instance.I don't know Paho MQTT library really well however I want to all my tasks executed through single MQTT client object.

```
#mqtt.py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

#The callback for connecting to CloudMQTT broker
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connecting to CloudMQTT broker: "+ mqtt.connack_string(rc))

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("Received message '" + str(message.payload) + "' on topic '"
        + message.topic  + "' with QoS " + str(message.qos))


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set('****', '****')
client.connect('****', ****),
```

My first terminal console:

```
>>> from mqtt import client
>>> client
<paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7fc7c4e3ce48>
```

My second terminal console:

```
>>> from mqtt import client
>>> client
<paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f437ea56e48>
```

Comment: When you run 2 terminal console sessions, then you have 2 python interpreter **processes**, which unlikely would be able to share a Client object.

Comment: It just an example, the thing I truly want is that there are 2 modules which sharing a Client object.